# Is there a "cleaner" way to parse a deliminated string if it only has one item?

Tags: java, regex, string, tokenize, delimiter

I have a String. This string has values which are separated by a comma (e.g Bob,John,Jill), but sometimes this String will only have one value (e.g Bob).
I need to extract these values so I use something like this:

```
String str = "Bob,John,Jill";
StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str , ",");
```

This works and I now have access to the 3 names individually., but what if my String only contains the word Bob (no comma now). This code fails so my solution is to check if a comma exists, and if it does then I tokanize, if not then I just get the string (I know this condition statement is not good because it does not handle null and other conditons properly, but I just want to keep it short to display the issue):

```
if( (str != null) && (!str.isEmpty()) && (!str.contains(",")) && (str.length() > 0)){
    // only 1 element exists, just use the string
}
else{
    //Tokenize
}
```

This does not seem like a very clean solution to me, is there any better methods to accomplish this where I can avoid conditional checks such as this?  I tried to work with regex, but could not work out a solution to account if there is only one element, or some third part library I can use?

Comment: Just add a comma to the start or end of the string

Comment: @EngineerDollery there are numerous common and perfectly functional string-splitting mechanisms in Java, why mangle your input in order to make it "work" with a broken, deprecated tool?

Comment: If I thought it was a good answer I'd have entered it as an answer, not a comment :) However, it does solve the problem doesn't it? BTW: In java, strings are immutable, so this doesn't actually 'mangle' the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

You should use a [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) instead.  You could just use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) (which is the JDK's suggested alternative), but it's [less powerful and has confusing trailing-delimiter handling](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter).

---

For educational purposes, here's how you could use a `Pattern` to do the same work (but again, just use `Splitter`):

```
// Matches up to the next comma or the end of the line
Pattern CSV_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,|$)");

List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = CSV_PATTERN.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
  ls.add(m.group(1).trim()); // .trim() is optional
}
```

The regex looks-backwards for a comma or the start of the string (to avoid a zero-width match at the end of the string), followed by zero or more non-comma characters, followed by a comma or the end of the line.

Comment: Yes split uses _regex_, e.g. if the delimiter is `.` you have to split by `\\.` or ` *\\. *`

Comment: That's clearly documented in `String.split()`; if you use a method without understanding what it does I think that's on you.  Nevertheless, `Splitter` lets you explicitly split on characters, strings, and regular expressions - another benefit over `String.split()`.

Comment: Suggest you specify "Guava's `Splitter`" to make it clear that it's not JDK. That's a showstopper for lots of projects.

Comment: Added an explicit link to Guava.  But if Guava is a showstopper for your project, I'm glad I'm not working on it :)

Comment: Will this then parse a single element with no comma?

Comment: @user2924127 Yes, it will work fine on a single element with no comma.